# JSF 2 @PostConstruct method called twice

Tags: jsf-2, postconstruct

I've got a strange behavior: my method annotated with `@PostConstruct` is called twice.

Debugging it, I saw that my search page called it before the command link's action methos `mbean.edit` was called. My bean `MBeanSearch` is request scoped, my `MBean` is view scoped.

My view search.xhtml:

```
<h:commandLink value="#{var.value}" action="#{mbean.edit}">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{var.id}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

I've also got a target view var.xhtml.

Relevant extract from my `MBean` bean:

```
    public String edit() {
        return "/pages/var.xhtml";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() { }
```

With this code, my `@PostConstruct`is called after my edit method and later it is called again.

I think that I'm using the `@PostConstruct` in a wrong way (I think `MBean` needs to be up before any method). But what is the alternative to edit an object in a page different from the search page?

Comment: We need additional information to trace the problem. As is, Michi's explanation is the most probable one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the view scoped managed bean `mbean` (I think, it is a bit unclear) is used in `search.xhtml` and `var.xhtml`.

When you call the action method your are still on view `search.xhtml`. You get a bean instance bound to view scope for this view and the first call to the `@PostConstruct` method.

The action method returns the view ID of the second page `var.xhtml` and JSF navigates to this page. If you use `mbean` in this page too, you get a new instance of the bean as the view changed. This explains the second call to the `@PostConstruct` method.